# Read multiple lines from xml

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I am trying to fetch data from a xml file in java using sax parser. I successfully got small amount of data but when data becomes too large and in multiple lines it gives only two lines of data, not all the lines. I am trying following code-

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
InputSource source = new InputSource(isr);
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xr = parser.getXMLReader();
GeofenceParametersXMLHandler handler = new GeofenceParametersXMLHandler();
xr.setContentHandler(handler);
xr.parse(source);
```

And my GeofenceParametersXMLHandler is-

```
private boolean inTimeZone = false;
private boolean inCoordinate = false;
private boolean outerBoundaryIs = false;
private boolean innerBoundaryIs = false;
private String timeZone;
private List<String> innerCoordinates = new ArrayList<String>();
private String outerCoordinates;

public String getTimeZone() {
    return timeZone;
}

public List<String> getInnerCoordinates() {
    return innerCoordinates;
}

public String getOuterCoordinates() {
    return outerCoordinates;
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    super.characters(ch, start, length);
    if (this.inTimeZone) {
        this.timeZone = new String(ch, start, length);
        this.inTimeZone = false;
    }

    if (this.inCoordinate && this.innerBoundaryIs) {
        this.innerCoordinates.add(new String(ch, start, length));
        this.inCoordinate = false;
        this.innerBoundaryIs = false;
    }

    if (this.inCoordinate && this.outerBoundaryIs) {
        this.outerCoordinates = new String(ch, start, length);
        this.inCoordinate = false;
        this.outerBoundaryIs = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name) throws SAXException {
    super.endElement(uri, localName, name);
}

@Override
public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
    super.startDocument();
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    super.startElement(uri, localName, name, attributes);

    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("timezone")) {
        this.inTimeZone = true;
    }

    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("outerBoundaryIs")) {
        this.outerBoundaryIs = true;
    }

    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("innerBoundaryIs")) {
        this.innerBoundaryIs = true;
    }

    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("coordinates")) {
        this.inCoordinate = true;
    }
}
```

And the xml file is-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">

<Placemark>
   <name>gx:altitudeMode Example</name>
   <timezone>EASTERN</timezone>
   <Polygon>
      <extrude>1</extrude>
      <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
      <outerBoundaryIs>
      <LinearRing>
         <coordinates>
        -77.05788457660967,38.87253259892824,100 
        -77.05465973756702,38.87291016281703,100 
        -77.05315536854791,38.87053267794386,100 
        -77.05552622493516,38.868757801256,100 
        -77.05844056290393,38.86996206506943,100 
        -77.05788457660967,38.87253259892824,100
      </coordinates>
    </LinearRing>
  </outerBoundaryIs>
</Polygon>
```

I always got two line of data for coordinates. But when they are in single line I got complete data. How to fetch complete data in multiple line?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `characters()` method won't necessarily give you all the text data in one go (this is a very common misconception, btw).

The proper approach is to concatenate all the data returned by successive calls to characters() (using a `StringBuilder` or similar). Once your `endElement()` method is called, you can then treat that text buffer as complete and process it as such.

From the doc:

> The Parser will call this method to report each chunk of character
>   data. SAX parsers may return all contiguous character data in a single
>   chunk, or they may split it into several chunks

Often you see that for a small XML doc one call to `characters()` will suffice. However as your XML doc increases in size, you'll find that due to buffering etc. you'll start getting multiple calls. Consequently each call treated on its own appears to be incomplete.

Comment: Then how to get complete data?

Comment: He wrote that in the next paragraph

Comment: To concatenate, simply use a StringBuilder (say) and call toString on that once your endElement() method is called

Comment: As mentioned above Use StringBuffer to append data returned by characters() method and convert it to string in the end element method.